# Python unicode problems on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, django, unicode

Having the following django view code that generates a CSV response from a database view:

```
def _get_csv_stats(request, **filterargs):
   result = GlobalStats.objects.select_related().filter(**filterargs).values_list('user__username',
                                                                                  'user__first_name','user__last_name',
                                                                                  'center__name', 'action_name',
                                                                                  'action_date').annotate(num = Count('id')).order_by("action_date")
   response = HttpResponse(mimetype = 'text/csv')
   response.write( codecs.BOM_UTF8 )
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=statistcs.csv'
   writer = UnicodeWriter(response)
   for value in result:
       writer.writerow([unicode(v) for v in value])
   return response
```

Some of the columns contain utf8 text. When I download the file and open it using Linux or Mac OS X I can see the text properly. But downloading and opening the file using windows XP strange characters appear in the place of the non-ASCII text. Converting the file from csv to xls using Open Office on linux and opening the file on windows xp will result with a readable file (no strange characters).

I can't see what I'm missing here as I don't work with win XP. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

The UnicodeWriter class I'm using is descibed [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers in each OS?  E.g., Opera, Chrome and Firefox run on all of them -- is the "strange characters" issue browser specific?  If you _download_ the CSV and open it directly in Excel or OOO, is it still strange -- or does it only look strange in the browser...?

Comment: @Alex it doesn't matter what I use to open it. The problem is that only win xp regards the file as ASCII text not unicode. When I open it with notepad and use save as to save it as unicode encoded text file everything looks fine. So writing a byte order marker isn't of any help. I'm assuming I've to instruct the browser that it's unicode encoded file in a response header.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the text is displayed properly depends on whether the font that is is being drawn in supports all Unicode characters. This is not a problem with your django.

Answer (score 0):

First: I don't know django, so maybe this is far off.

Check whether your writer actually outputs UTF-8, if you write an UTF-8 BOM into the file. Unicode and UTF-8 are not the same. Also, afaikt, does Windows Notepad understand a UTF-8 BOM, so you getting "strange" characters can mean two things:

a) the rest of the file is not really UTF-8-encoded, try `v.encode('utf-8')` for that

b) the characters your trying to display are not supported by the font